# Olympiad number theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Find all sequences of consecutive prime numbers $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_k)$ such that:

- (a) $p_1 < p_2 < ... < p_k, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$
- (b) $p_1 = 2$
- (c) There exist $21$ consecutive positive integers such that each of them is divisible by at least one of the terms of the sequence $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_k)$.

I tried separation of cases when $k$ is greater than $19$ and when it is smaller, but I couldn't go any further. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: $a)$ is obvious if the $p_i$'s are consecutive primes. $a)$ and $b)$ would have simply be covered by "the first $k$ prime numbers"

Comment: Yes Peter you are right however I just quoted the problem text like it is

Comment: For $k\ge 21$ , we can use the chinese remainder theorem to prove that such $21$ consecutive positive integers can be found. But this number can surely be dropped significantly.

Comment: Can you show me please how to use the Chinese reminder theorem here I am not very familiar with it

Comment: For $k=6$ , there is still a solution. You can begin with $9440$

Comment: For $k=5$ , I did not find a solution yet. I guess we can prove that there is none, but I have no idea. Someone else here surely can it.

Comment: Questions from previous contests are welcome here, on the proviso that you say which contest the question is from, and the year it was asked (so we can independently verify that it isn't current). See the policy for contest questions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy). Please edit in the contest and year in which you found this question, or your question may be closed and/or down-voted.

Comment: It is a problem proposed by a friend of mine  when I said it is context math I meant olympiad or Challenging problems I don't know from which context  this  was taken

Comment: For $k=5$, the Chinese remainder theorem says you only need to check up to $2310$. That may be a lot to do by hand, but you basically only need to demonstrate primes (or composites with all prime factors greater than 11) that are decently distributed in that range. Which is to say, you need to find a little over 100 of them, or find some run of 21 consecutive integers with no such numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum $k=6$. The problem is to identify a sequence $x_0+n$ for $1\le n\le 21$.

At most one member of that sequence can be divisible by $11$ but not by $2$ or $3$. At most two members of that sequence can be divisible by $7$ but not by $2$ or $3$. At most two members of that sequence can be divisible by $5$ but not by $2$ or $3$. If we do not rely on divisibility by $13$, then at least sixteen of the members of the sequence must be divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Analysis of series of $21$ consecutive numbers $\bmod 6$ reveals that there can be as few as $13$ but at most $15$ numbers NOT coprime to $6$, i.e. being divisible by either $2$ or $3$. That is, there at least six numbers in such a sequence that are not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Thus, to ensure divisibility be the first $k$ primes, we must include $p_6=13$.